# opencart 3.0 хлебные крошки при seo_url

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Есть сайт на opencart 3.0 twig. На некоторых товарах прописан seo_url и из-за этого хлебные крошки выглядят так Главная-товар. Как сделать, чтоб была в хлебных крошках Категория и Подкатегория, чтоб отображался весь путь?

Comment: Тема дефолтная или сторонняя? На отвар переходите из категорий/подкатегорий или баннеров/слайдеров?

Comment: тема сторонняя. Перехожу из категорий/подкатегорий